# compare dot(.) on specific position using regex

Tags: regex

I have few input 
ex.

```
1.5 //acceptable
12.15 // acceptable
123.15 //not acceptable
12345 // not acceptable
```

dot(.) is acceptable only in 2nd and 3rd position otherwise wrong input. and all character must be numeric.

can regex helps for this criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d+$
```

This is the regex you're looking for

Explaination:

Your string must start (`^`) with a digit symbol (`\d`) repeated one or two times (`{1,2}`) then there should be a dot symbol (`\.` <-- you must escape dot char as otherwise it will represent any character into regex syntax) followed by at least a digit (`\d`) that is also the final part of the string (`$`)

Comment: it helps me. thanks for explaination. need little modification `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}`